# select non-duplicated records

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, not-exists

I have a table with about 50 millions records.

the table structure is something like below and both **callerid** and **call_start** fields are indexed.

> id -- callerid -- call_start

I want to select all records that their call_start is greater than '2013-12-22' and callerid is not duplicated before '2013-12-22' in whole table.

I used something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ca.`callerid` 
FROM
  call_archives AS ca 
WHERE ca.`call_start` >= '2013-12-22' 
  AND ca.`callerid` NOT IN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT 
    ca.`callerid` 
  FROM
    call_archives AS ca 
  WHERE ca.`call_start` < '2013-12-21')
```

but this is extremely slow, any suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just curious if this query works fast or not on your table:

```
SELECT ca.`callerid` 
FROM call_archives 
GROUP BY ca.`callerid` 
HAVING MIN(ca.`call_start`) >='2013-12-22'
```

Comment: magnificent improvement in query execution time. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try with `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  ca.`callerid` 
FROM
  call_archives AS ca 
WHERE ca.`call_start` >= '2013-12-22' 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 
    1 
  FROM
    call_archives AS cb 
  WHERE ca.`callerid` = cb.`callerid` 
    AND cb.`call_start` < '2013-12-21')
```

Comment: this improved execution time, but not as much as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ca.callerid 
FROM call_archives AS ca 
WHERE ca.call_start>='2013-12-22' AND 
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM call_archives AS ca1 
             WHERE ca.callerid = ca1.callerid AND ca1.call_start <'2013-12-21');
```